# Понимание позиции и разрешения экрана: как правильно установить позицию объекта?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я разрабатываю 2d игру. У меня есть объект - спрайт (в компоненте SpriteRenderer я установил спрайт). Я пытаюсь установить его в верхний левый угол экрана.

Я бы хотел, чтоб он был в этой позиции (верхний левый угол, к примеру) при любом разрешении экрана (Я разрабатываю под iOS, поэтому в сейчас я говорю про разрешения под iPhone, retina, не retina, iPad и прочие)

Я привык, что обычно нулевые координаты системы 0,0 начинаются с нижнего левого угла или верхнего левого. Однако, в *Unity*, похоже 0,0 указывают на центр объекта. По большому счету это не является проблемой, но это немного сбивает с толку.
Если я вывожу ширину объекта (которая равна 128px) - я получаю значение **1.06**. Экран, как я понимаю, разделен виртуально на секции, где край слева равен -3, а справа +3

Вопрос: Почему ширина спрайта 1.06? Как мне правильно размещать объекты в этой системе? Например, представим, что у меня есть спрайт 128px*128px и я его хочу поместить точно в верхний левый угол. Как это сделать?

<sub>Переведено с  https://stackoverflow.com/q/22594074/6104996</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Когда вы импортируете картинку в *Unity* и устанавливаете тип спрайт (т.е. `Texture Type = Sprite`), то в том же меню вы должны были заметить также атрибут "Pixels To Units".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

100 пикселей соответствует 1 юнити метру. Таким образом, ваши 128 пикселей (если оставить дефолтные настройки) должны быть равны 1.28 юнитам (Units). Это значение отличается от вашего 1.06, но это, скорее всего потому, что
ваш спрайт не имеет единообразную форму или уже вы выставили *Pixels To Units* в другое значение или вы уже изменили значение *scale* своего спрайта. Проверьте, что эти значения не были изменены. Поставьте их в наши дефолтные значения.

Далее. Размер "Size" ортографической камеры соответсвует половине её высоты.

На изображении ниже ортографическая камера будет видеть область, выделенная белым прямоугольником. Размер (Size) 5 - значит 10 юнитов высоту. Изображение цветка имеет размеры 128px в ширину и 96px в выосту, которая имеет дефолтные
настройки 1 unit = 100 pixels.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Учитывая то, что вы хотите использовать спрайт и нужно, чтобы каждый кадр он оставался в верхнем левом углу при любом разрещении, то можно теперь воспользоваться следующим кодом, который нужно прикрепить к спрайту:

```
void Update () {
    float camHalfHeight = Camera.main.orthographicSize;
    float camHalfWidth = Camera.main.aspect * camHalfHeight; 

    Bounds bounds = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().bounds;

    // Устанавливаем новый вектор в верхний левый угол 
    Vector3 topLeftPosition = new Vector3(-camHalfWidth, camHalfHeight, 0) + Camera.main.transform.position; 

    // Устанавливаем смещение на основе размера объекта
    topLeftPosition += new Vector3(bounds.size.x / 2, -bounds.size.y / 2, 0);

    transform.position = topLeftPosition;        
}
```

---

В некоторых случаях возможно, что спрайт будет чуть выше, чем верхний край камеры. Тогда можно привести отображение из экранного пространства в мировое пространство. В этом случае размеры экрана определяется в пикселях. 
Т.к. в данном случае левая нижняя часть экрана имеет координаты (0,0); правая верхняя ([pixelWidth](http://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/ScriptReference/Camera-pixelWidth.html), pixelHeight), a положение z в мировых единицах от камеры, то поместить изображение в верхний левый угол надо будет так:

```
void Update () {
    Bounds bounds = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().bounds;
    Vector3 topLeftPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (new Vector3 (0, Camera.main.pixelHeight, Camera.main.nearClipPlane));    
    // Устанавливаем смещение на основе размера объекта
    topLeftPosition += new Vector3(bounds.size.x / 2, -bounds.size.y / 2, 0);

    transform.position = topLeftPosition;        
}
```

<sub>Ответ переведен и дополнен отсебятинкой с https://stackoverflow.com/a/22596935/6104996</sub>